# Tensorflow object detection training issues

Tags: tensorflow, training-data

Following EdjeElectronics tensorflow object detection tutorial i have some issues and question.

i use faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco

followed the tutorial for training my own model (only one class)

I train my own model with only one class to detect and almost 400 pictures (320 train, 80 test)

1. After only 85 step the classification_loss is under 0.2. and after 600 steps it is near 0.1 so don't need to train more.

why it train like that ? normally i have to train 10000 or 20000

2. when i itry the detection on picture with 1 trained object and one another in same category but not same appearence it is detected as the first one.

Any idea ? [image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the loss is lower like that but for the oher question i tried with ssd_inception2 model detection, with 400 step i have the same problem, but with 701 step it is better , it could make difference between 2 similar objects[image]